# How to add Legend to x.plot() - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that I have turned into a line chart. I can do it with matplotlib, but I like the look of the simple 'x.plot()' functionality.

So my code looks like this:

```
x = lineFDF[threeYr]
y = lineFDF[twoYr]
a = lineFDF[oneYr]
b = lineFDF[Yr]
x.plot()
y.plot()
a.plot()
b.plot()
```

Which produces this:

[image]

How do I add a legend for it using the column headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
x.plot(label='mylabel')
...
plt.legend()  # assuming you imported like: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But as your code is quite incomplete, there is nothing to test. (It also looks like you are using pandas, which wraps matplotlib; would have not hurt to mention stuff like that)

Comment: Perfect, adding: plt.legend() to the end of the code does what I need it to do. Really appreciate your quick response, I will mark your answer as complete as soon as I am able to :)